# Simple way to import and export and store Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, import, export

For example I have something like this.

```
var Ar : Array;
Ar[0] = 'apple';
Ar[3] = 'pineapple';
Ar[12] = 'car';
Ar[33] = 'dog';
Ar[41] = 'cat';
Ar[21] = 'apple';
```

And I need to store it in simple text file. Like this

```
ArText : String ;
ArtText = "0-Apple,3-pineapple,12-car,33-dog,41-cat,21-apple"
```

You got the point.

What is best way to convert Array in to a readable string, and then back? Javascript code will be best, but you can use almost any similiar.

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 4):

My initial impulse was to convert it directly to [JSON](http://json.org/), but then I realised that `JSON.stringify()` would return something like this:

```
["apple",null,null,"pineapple",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"car",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"apple",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"dog",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"cat"]
```

Because your array has a bunch of undefined slots that all become `null` because JSON doesn't support undefined values. Which would be OK if you just need to store it except then when you convert it back to an array you'd end up with nulls everywhere instead of undefined so you'd have to allow for that (not a big deal) but in any case it sounds like you want it to be human-readable too.

So instead I suggest you convert it to an object and then convert the object to JSON using [`JSON.stringify()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). To convert it back you use [`JSON.parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to turn your string into an object, then loop through the object properties to create a sparse array.

**What I'm proposing would result in a JSON string like this:**

```
{"0":"apple","3":"pineapple","12":"car","21":"apple","33":"dog","41":"cat"}
```

The code:

```
function sparseArrayStringify(arr) {
    var obj = {},
        i;
    for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
       if (typeof arr[i] != "undefined")
           obj[i] = arr[i];
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}

function parseToSparseArray(str) {
    var arr = [],
        obj = JSON.parse(str),
        k;
    for (k in obj)
        arr[k] = obj[k];
    return arr;
}

var stringifiedArray = sparseArrayStringify(Ar); // where Ar is your array

// and change it back
var anArray = parseToSparseArray(stringifiedArray);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XXqVD/

Note: in my `parseToSparseArray()` function I didn't bother testing that the properties of the object in the string being parsed actually are non-negative integers, but you can add that if desired.

Newer browsers support the `JSON` object with associated methods, or for older browsers you can include the [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library.

By the way, the code in your question is invalid JavaScript: you can't declare variables with a type in JS. See the examples in my code for how to declare arrays, objects, etc.

**EDIT: OK, I don't know why on earth you'd want the non-JSON version when JSON is a well known standard format, but here are some untested functions that read and write exactly the format from the question:**

```
"0-Apple,3-pineapple,12-car,33-dog,41-cat,21-apple"
```

**Note that your proposed format won't work if any of the array elements contain commas or hyphens.** Which is why JSON is the way you should go. Anyway:

```
function serialiseArray(arr) {
    var workingArray = [],
        i;
    for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
       if (typeof arr[i] != "undefined")
           workingArray.push(i + "-" + arr[i]);
    return workingArray.join(",");
}

function deserialiseArray(str) {
    var arr = [],
        items = str.split(","),
        item,
        i;
    for (i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        item = items[i].split("-");
        arr[item[0]] = item[1];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's *just* strings in the array, you could use the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method on the `Array` object to create a comma separated string, and then use the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) method on the `String` object to convert the string back to an array.

```
var Ar = new Array;
Ar[0] = 'apple';
Ar[3] = 'pineapple';
Ar[12] = 'car';
Ar[33] = 'dog';
Ar[41] = 'cat';
Ar[21] = 'apple';

var stringRepresentation = Ar.join(",");
var backToArray = stringRepresentation.split(";");
```

You can see this working here; http://jsfiddle.net/ykQRX/. Note I've also fixed your invalid JavaScript (`var Ar = new Array;`).

Comment: Your code will output string like this "apple,,,pineapple,,,,,,,,,car,,,,,,,,,apple,,,,,,,,,,,,dog,,,,,,,,cat" Its not very readble. I need something more compact like "1-apple, 3-pineapple..."